# Having different validation settings for different pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have an application with slider header images that rotate with JS. Now, I've provided admin with the option to choose which page the uploaded slider will be displayed on, they have the choice between the landing page and the index page.

Here is how my slider model looks:

```
class Slider < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :short_text, presence: true

  has_attached_file :image, styles: {
      medium: '800x>',
      small: '300x>'
  }

  validates_attachment_content_type :image, :content_type => /\Aimage\/.*\Z/
  validates :image, dimensions: { width: 1024, height: 427 }, on: :create

  SLIDER_TYPES = {
    0 => "Both (Landing and Index page)",
    1 => "Index page",
    2 => 'Landing page'
  }
end
```

The issue is, I'd like to allow the admin to upload larger images for the index page and keep the current dimension validations i.e. `width: 1024, height: 427` solely for the landing page.

Is it possible to set different validations for the different pages based on my above code?

Any help here would be great!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create [**`custom validation methods`**](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-methods) and *inside your method you can check for your slider_type and then accordingly validate its dimension*, something like:

```
class Slider < ActiveRecord::Base
  validate :check_for_dimension

  def check_for_dimension
    # your logic to check type and apply dimension accordingly
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks Mandeep! It might be the lack of coffee/just waking up but I'm having trouble thinking through the best logic for the check_for_dimensions method. Care to add that to your answer and I'll accept. Cheers!

Comment: if dimensions: {width: 1024, height: 427}
      Slider::SLIDER_TYPES == 1
    else
      Slider::SLIDER_TYPES == 2
    end

Comment: @user3399101 i thought you wanted to do it other way around, i mean check for variable and then accordingly apply dimension